# Inverse Fourier Transform of the output, Y(f)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, self-learning, laplace-transform

A linear system is defined by the differential equation:

$$
y''(t) + 4y'(t) + 25y(t)= x(t)
$$

The transfer function of this system is:

$$
H(f) = \frac{Y(f)}{X(f)}= \frac{1}{(2\pi fj)^{2}+ 4(2\pi fj)+ 25}
$$

The question asked to find the output *y(t)* when the input *x(t)* is 
$$ cos(4t + \frac{\pi }{4}) $$

First, I found the Fourier Transform of *x(t)* which equals:

$$
X(f) =\left [ \frac{1}{2}\delta (f - \frac{2}{\pi}) + \frac{1}{2}\delta (f + \frac{2}{\pi}) \right ]e^{j\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}f}
$$

I know that the Inverse Fourier Transform of

$$
G(f)\delta(f - f_{0}) \Leftrightarrow G(f_{0})e^{2 \pi f_{0}jt} $$ 
$$  G(f)\delta(f + f_{0}) \Leftrightarrow G(-f_{0})e^{-2 \pi f_{0}jt} $$

Therefore my *y(t)* would be equal to:

$$
y(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left [ \frac{e^{\pi j}}{(4j)^{2} + (16j) + 25} \right ]e^{j4t} + \frac{1}{2}\left [ \frac{e^{-\pi j}}{(-4j)^{2} - (16j) + 25} \right ]e^{-j4t}$$

$$
= \frac{e^{\pi j}}{32j + 18}e^{j4t}+\frac{e^{-\pi j}}{- 32j + 18}e^{-j4t}
$$

What do you think about my solution?

**Update:**
I'm still not satisfied with $e^{\pm \pi j}$

Comment: I don't know Fourier transforms, but just to confirm: $j$ is the imaginary unit, right? (as is common in EE, but not as common in math)

Comment: @anorton Yes. It's imaginary.

Comment: Closely related to [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/13404/235) on dsp.SE

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are chasing me lol. I'm just checking if I understood the topic well. Thanks though!

Comment: Plug your proposed solution into the equation and check it. I'm curious, though, as to why you're not using the Laplace transform instead, which is ideally suited for $t \ge 0$ problems.

Comment: @T.A.E. Well, I think since I have _cos(t)_ with time shift, Fourier Transform is easier for me.

Comment: @Sultan: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cos(4t + \pi/4) = \frac{e^{j(4t + \pi/4)} + e^{-j(4t + \pi/4)}}{2} = U + U^*\\ \text{ where } U = \frac{e^{j \pi/4}}{2} e^{j 4t}$$ 
Hence $$
Y = V + V^* \text{  where  } V = \frac{e^{j \pi/4}}{2} H(j4)e^{j 4t}$$
by basic properties of Fourier transforms and transfer functions.

Finally, if you want the answer in trigonometric functions then write $H$ in polar form as
$$
H(j4) = M e^{j \phi} $$
Then $$
y(t) = M \cos({4t + \pi/4 + \phi})
$$

Comment: The Fourier Transform of a shifted function is $$ g(t - t_{0}) \Leftrightarrow G(f)e^{-j2\pi ft_{0}} $$

So, don't you think that $ e^{j \frac{\pi}{4}} $ should be $ e^{j \frac{\pi^{2}}{2}f}? $

Comment: No. $e^j\pi/4$ is a constant (actually the amplitude of the complex exponential).

Comment: I'm sorry! I still didn't get. If there is a shift in time, that means there is $e^{-j2\pi ft_{0}}$ in the _f_ domain.
Do you agree with me for _X(f)_?

Comment: Yes but you are going back to time domain when you calculate y(t). So the same shift shows up in y(t). In this case the shifted time "$4t+\pi/4$" shows up in y(t) unchanged. $H$ just adds additional shift of $\phi$.

Comment: I did not check your answer, but if you simplify it, you may get the same answer as me. I don't have a calculator or anything here to do the computation

Comment: Well, my answer is the same is yours except $e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Mine has $e^{j\pi}$

Comment: I've tried many times to get the same answer as yours but I couldn't. Can you help?